Extending / Replacing coax cable of PCB 5G antenna
I have 10 of the following 5G antennas:
Taoglas MAT.176A <-- Datasheet
This is a 5G antenna with four 10cm (4inches) long 1.13 coaxial cables soldered on. The coax cables attach to a 5G modem using IPEX MHF4 connector.
Those 10cm (4inch) are too short it needs to be at least 15cm (6inch). Is it possible to extend the coaxial cables without compromising signal quality? Are there extension cables that extend the length using the MHF4 connector? Or is it possible to desolder the 4 cables and solder on longer ones without messing with the signal quality? How would someone with knowledge go about extending the cables?
I would hate having to throw away those antennas.


Is it possible to extend the coaxial cables without compromising signal quality?

No, anything in this universe has losses; and this is especially true for miniature microwave connectors and microwave cabling.
However, I don't think an addition 0.5 dB to 1.8 dB (wild guess) for two more connectors would really break any 5G application per se – after all, this is a wireless technology, and thus there's unknown attenuations in the ranges of 90 dB, easily, anyway. You do make your device a bit worse, but that bit might not be observable or matter.

Are there extension cables that extend the length using the MHF4 connector?

Possibly? I don't know; did mouser or Digikey or farnell turn up nothing?
In that case, your best bet might be special ordering 40 of such cables, or making a simple (and small) PCB that allows your extension using "pigtail" cables that have the same IPEX MHF4 connector on both ends. That will undoubtedly have a fair bit more loss than just expert-made extension cables, but that might a) still be totally OK and b) have the advantage of being possible to bring into existence.

So extending either by additional pcb or via an extender i might find on mouser would be preferable to just desoldering the coax cables and soldering on longer ones?

if you can solder them to a degree where you're confident enough, sure, that is a good approach; it's not "not messing with signal quality" (as any other option). You asked how someone would go about extending the cables, so I didn't go into detail replacing them :) But sure, that would actually be preferable over introducing more connectors. Question really is if you're OK doing that soldering. It does look fiddly.

You'll want a good soldering iron, probably a hot air station to preheat the board, if the outer conductor of the cable and the ground planes suck away too much heat, solder wick to clean up the pads after desoldering, something to cleanly remove the outer insulation, conductor hull, inner dielectric from the inner conductor of you new cables, and a steady hand/kind of third hand device to hold the cables straight while soldering them on; I can't tell by the photos, but I think you might also want fine pliers to bend the center conductor so it touches the pad. Probably, you want liquid flux.

That might be doable, I was more worried about messing with the impedance when "simply" soldering on longer 1.13 coax cables with the right connector. But it seems I was wrong.

Oh, you will mess with the impedance! That will introduce losses, yes. But assuming you'll use the same cable type, and try to match the original geometry closely, these should be < 2 dB worse than the original.
